# error malloc in C

Tags: c, malloc

I'm not sure whats wrong with this it says incompatible implicit built in func 
Well I did include string.h file but it still giving me a error

```
 int name_read;
 int name_bytes = 100;
 char *name;

 printf("Please enter name:\n");
 name = (char *)malloc(name_bytes + 1);
 name_read = getline(&name, &name_bytes, stdin);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `#include <stdlib.h>` to get the correct declaration of `malloc`.

Also `sizeof(name_bytes) + 1` looks fishy;  that will give you 5 bytes of memory, not 101 as you probably expected.

Finally, there is no need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C since it returns a `void*`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
/* ... */
int name_bytes = 100;
char* name = malloc(name_bytes + 1);
```

Comment: I was originally using it in a getline forgot to include that and didn't want want it to return as a void* >.<

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, make sure you've included stdlib.h.  Also, you should note that sizeof returns the size of a variable/type, not the value assigned to the variable.  So your sizeof(name_bytes) will return the size of an integer in bytes, not 100

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually need `name = malloc(name_bytes + 1);` (assuming you want to allocate 101 bytes for name)